# Problema para enviar datos por get en laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, get

No se cual es el motivo por le cual el dato "subred" enviado por *get* no llega al modelo y me sale el siguiente error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Equipamiento::scopeRelaciones(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 1166 and exactly 3 expected

Esta es la función *scopeRelaciones* que da el error:

```
public function scopeRelaciones($query, $tipo, $subred)
```

Y este este código se encuentra en el controlador:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $tipo_equipamiento = DB::table('tipo_equipamiento')->orderBy('equipamiento','asc')->get();
    $ips = DB::table('ips')->orderBy('nombre', 'asc')->get();

    $equipamientos = Equipamiento::Ip($request->get('ip'))
        ->Equipo($request->get('equipo'))
        ->Relaciones($request->get('tipo', 'subred'))
        ->Puesto($request->get('puesto'))
        ->Area($request->get('area'))
        ->Usuario($request->get('usuario'))
        
        ->paginate(20);

    return view ('equipamiento.inicio', array('equipamientos'=>$equipamientos, 'equipo'=>$request->get('equipo'),'puesto'=>$request->get('puesto'),
        'ip'=>$request->get('ip'),'tipo_equipamiento'=> $tipo_equipamiento, 'tipo'=>$request->get('tipo'), 'ips' => $ips, 'subred' => $request->get('subred'),
        'usuario'=>$request->get('usuario'), 'area'=>$request->get('area')));
}
```

Comment: ¿Que devuelve `$request->get('tipo', 'subred')` cuando haces `->Relaciones($request->get('tipo', 'subred'))`? Creo que tendrías que pasarle cada valor cada argumento, si no  `$request->get('tipo', 'subred')` queda en el segundo argumento y el tercero queda vacío

Comment: `$request->get('tipo', 'subred')` devuelve 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto, se debian separarar los datos enviados ya que tomaba solo el primero.

```
 ->Relaciones($request->get('tipo'), $request->get('subred'))
```